# How to Ignore a Soft Deleted field and Check for Unique Value in Laravel Validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

My table schema has the following structure:

```
e_base
s_id | e_id | e_name    | deleted_at
4   1   estatex | 2018-05-25 13:33:36

Validation Rule:

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'e_id'  =>  'required|unique:e_base,e_id'
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
   return Response::json($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();, 400);
}
```

MY laravel version is 5.2 and I can't get my head around that rule. Hope someone help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
   'e_id'  =>  'required|unique:e_base,e_id,deleted_at,NULL'
]);
```

This will ignore the deleted_at having a value rather than NULL .

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'e_id'  =>  'required|unique:e_base,e_id,NULL,e_id,deleted_at,NULL'
    ]);
```

this says only check in the e_base table when a deleted_at column is equal to null and ignore rows with e_id  equal NULL(just for do like pattern). for more information visit this [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 0):

I love the '[Adding Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)' paragraph mentions in the Laravel documentation.

By using the custom query logic, we have full control. Otherwise, we have to think about the position of element name for unique rule before adding simple validation logic. Hopefully the following solution work for others.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('e_base')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
        })
    ],
]);
```

Comment: What if the deleted_at column has a 0 instead of null ? I tried :         ```$aValidationRules["start"] = Rule::unique('App\Models\WorkTime', 'tstamp_start')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('deleted_at', '!=', 0);
});
``` but it still isn't working.